# using sed to replace a string in all files of a directory

Tags: regex, linux, sed, terminal

I am trying to find and replace all occurances of this:

```
 #include <boost
```

with this:

```
#include </home/pi/Desktop/boost_1_66_0/boost
```

for the libraries to work. here is what i came up with:

```
sed -i 's/#include <boost/#include <\/home\/pi\/Desktop\/boost_1_66_0\/boost/g' *
```

but gives me this:

> sed: couldn't edit build: not a regular file

did i escape the '/' wrong or is # the problem?

Comment: i want all files in that directory and all of its subdirectories to be searched

Comment: Can you list the files this is supposed to process? I am especially interested where the "build" is coming from. Could it be one of the file names? Since the error message complains about it not being a regular file, that information would be helpful, too. Maybe you could provide the output of `ls -l`.

Comment: im trying to build [openvibe](http://openvibe.inria.fr/downloads/) source code and its probably a script in there cause the other answer did the job

Answer (score 19, accepted):

It looks like `build` is a directory and you can't run `sed` on a directory. One option, if your directory tree is only one deep is to use a final argument `*/*` instead of `*`. For an arbitrarily deep directory structure a more effective method is to use `find` to find all the files and run `sed` on them:

```sh
find . -type f -exec sed -i 's/from/to/' {} \;
```

This uses `find` to start in the current directory and recursively descend the directory tree. For each regular file (`-type f`) it finds, it will run the command given to the `-exec` option. It substitutes the `{}` with the files it found.

Comment: Consider using `{} +` so that you don't invoke `sed` for each file.

Comment: @PesaThe Thanks I didn't know about that option. Nice to not have to use `xargs` for that. I don't usually bother with this since I've found that if the cost of invoking `sed` so many times is noticeable I'm also more likely to run into command line length limits.

Answer (score -1):

I think sed is missing the '/g' part to end the command.
This works for me

```
find . -type f -name '*.py' -exec sed -i 's/from/to/g' {} \; -ls
```

restricting the search with pattern and show which files has been considering.

Comment: The `/g` flag is only useful if you require the pattern to be substituted multiple times _in one line._ This is a common `sed` beginner error, as such.